# make errors when trying to install gcc46 with brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rvm, homebrew

I'm getting this over and over no matter what I try

```
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-4.6.4/gcc-4.6.4.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc46-4.6.4.tar.bz2
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gc
==> make bootstrap
echo timestamp > s-automata
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues
```

An ideas what is causing it, can I run something to get some better logs, I'm not sure how to find logs or if that's even possible, I'm trying to isntall and get rails up and running per the railstutorial.org book

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew put logs at `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew`

And you can also try the following command to capture error logs:

```
brew install <formula> 2>&1 | tee install.log
```

More info can be found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10430).

Comment: I think it was the yosemite beta, I opened a log and saw that there were some things that were saying it was trying to force a stable version for yosemite and I guess there isn't yet with some of the things I need to install. So I switched back to mavericks and everything is installing just fine.